# LINQ with Generic Parameter

Tags: .net, linq

I have a simple function to get a list of conference rooms from DB.
I am using the following function:

```
    public List<ConferenceRoom> RunRoomQuery<T1>(T1 fieldValue, Func<ConferenceRoom, T1, bool> predicate)
    {
        var confRooms = _dataContext.ConferenceRooms.Where(delegate(ConferenceRoom c)
        {
            return predicate(c, fieldValue);
        });
        return confRooms.ToList();
    }
```

It works fine; but as you noticed, I am passing a "ConferenceRoom" type.
Instead, I would like to make it more generic and pass T2 like this:

```
    public List<T2> RunRoomQuery<T1,T2>(T1 fieldValue, Func<T2, T1, bool> predicate)
    {
        var confRooms = _dataContext.ConferenceRooms.Where(delegate(T2 c)
        {
            return predicate(c, fieldValue);
        });
        return confRooms.ToList();
    }
```

confRoom.ToList() doesn't compile and "Where" is not happy about it either.

QUESTION: WHY? WHAT IS IT THAT I AM MISSING?
Following are errors:

```
error CS0305: Using the generic method 'ConferenceDB.ConferenceDb.RunRoomQuery<T1,T2>(T1, System.Func<T2,T1,bool>)' requires 2 type arguments
C:\Projects\ConferenceDB\ConferenceDB.cs(82,25): (Related location)
C:\Projects\ConferenceDB\ConferenceDB.cs(69,27): error CS0305: Using the generic method 'ConferenceDB.ConferenceDb.RunRoomQuery<T1,T2>(T1, System.Func<T2,T1,bool>)' requires 2 type arguments
```

Why?

Comment: Your generic type here has to be compatible with the `ConferenceRooms` collection. `.ToList()` won't work unless the items returned from the query are the same as `T2`.  You also have to be careful that `.Where()` doesn't return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are expecting a list of type `List<ConferenceRoom>` to be cast to `List<T2>`.

Without a constraint on T2 that is not possible.

```
public List<T2> RunRoomQuery<T1,T2>(T1 fieldValue, Func<T2, T1, bool> predicate) where T2 : ConferenceRoom
```

I also suspect the type of `_dataContext.ConferenceRooms` is `IEnumerable<ConferenceRoom>`, so even with the above constraint it will not work.

I cannot really offer a better solution as I do not understand why you want to make it generic?

Comment: The reason I want to make it more generic is that I want to run all other queries like getting " all users with Admin privileges" for example, by passing a new predicate and User type for T2....I am new to this whole LINQ and C# so I thought I could use some help....I can not put a constraint because these are un-related types that I want to pass...I could fake by deriving each one from some common dummy type but that may or may not work ...not sure

Comment: And what variable are the users stored in? Is it '_dataContext.ConferenceRooms'?

Comment: I suspect you are trying to **over generalize**, and that the above function is adding more complexity than it is solving. Something I am also quite good at ;) If you add the code you are trying to simplify I  can share some ideas.

Comment: _datacontext.Users stores users

Comment: In that case I cannot see this method helping. I often find its best to write the code, then simplify it. Have you written the filtering code yet?

Answer (score 1):

`_dataContext.ConferenceRooms` is a collection of `ConferenceRoom`s.
Therefore, it's `Where()` extension method takes a `ConferenceRoom`, not a `T2`.

---

The point of a generic method is to be **generic** – to work with different types.
It makes no sense to make your method generic, since it only works with `ConferenceRoom`s.

Comment: ok this was a good answer....here is what I am trying to do....end-user will query for different types of data items...like : give me all the conference room with capacity > 5.....give me all conference rooms with Location 'upper floor' ....They can also query for something like:'give me all users who have booked conference room' ...and so on...but there is a finite number (defined at compile time) queries they will make....i was hoping (by being lazy perhaps) to get away with writing one generic function with appropriate predicaTe which filter data out...THERE HAS TO BE A BETTER OR SOME WAY